# Define constructor in Java

Tags: java

I would like to know how can I define constructor in Java.
I started writing piece of code but I get errors.

```
package xyz;

public class ConstructorExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public ConstructorExample(int x,int y){
//          private double x,y;
        }   

    }

}
```

Can I write constructor in class with main or I must have another class? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constuctor must be like any other method declared (but it has to be called same, as the class name, and do not provide any return):

```
public class ConstructorExample {
    //this is your class fieald
    private double x,y;

    //here is the constructor
    public ConstructorExample(int x,int y){
       //set the class field's values, via this (means class), 
       //because the arg names is the same as fields names
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //here is how you can create a class instance inside the main method 
        ConstructorExample example = new ConstructorExample(1,1); 
    }    
}
```

Furthermore, if you have not defined any constructor, java will add the default one, without arguments. So it could look like:

```
public class ConstructorExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //here is how you can create a class instance inside the main method 
        //with the default constructor
        ConstructorExample example = new ConstructorExample(); 
    }    
}
```

And if you have a number of constructors, then you can call one from another via `this` again, like:

```
public class ConstructorExample {
    //this is your class fieald
    private double x,y;

    //here is the constructor with the single argument
    public ConstructorExample(int x){
       this.x = x;
    } 

    //here is the constructor with 2 arguments
    public ConstructorExample(int x,int y){
       //you can call another constructor with the arguments
       this(x);
       this.y = y;
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //here is how you can create a class instance inside the main method 
        ConstructorExample example = new ConstructorExample(1,1); 
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define a Constructor inside a method. You have to declare it like any other method in the class body.

```
package xyz;

public class ConstructorExample {

    public ConstructorExample(int x,int y){
//      private double x,y;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Comment: `ConstructorExample` doesn't inherit default constructor, since it has one with parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Of corse you can write a constructor for `Main`. Any class, enum and abstract class can have a constructor.

**Simple usage**

```
public Main(){
    //Constructor code here...
}
```

Then to call main just use:
    `Main main = new Main ();`

Note: private, protected and public modifiers can be used with a constructor.

**The reason your getting an error in your code**

Your attempting to create a method inside a method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    public ConstructorExample(int x,int y){
        //private double x,y;
    }   

}
```

Your attempting to create the constructor in your main method which is illigal syntax. The correct way to do it is:

```
class ConstructorExample {

    //This is the constructor
    public ConstructorExample(){
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ConstructorExample example = new ConstructorExample();//This calls the constructor when creating the class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how can I define constructor in Java. I started
>   writing piece of code but I get errors.

Error is because constructor is defined inside main() method. Need to move outside. You can call from main method.

> Java constructors are special methods that are called when an object
>   is instantiated. In other words, when you use the new keyword. The
>   constructor initializes the newly created object.

```
package xyz;

public class ConstructorExample {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public ConstructorExample(int x,int y){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConstructorExample example = new ConstructorExample(1,1); 
    }

    }
```